# How to escape parentheses on a string as a Regex using replace on javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace a regular expression (a string), the string is `url(../img/content/blocks.svg) no-repeat scroll transparent;`

My script is

```
var content = content.replace(/url(../img/content/blocks.svg) no-repeat scroll transparent;/g, "none;");
```

This makes an error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: You need to escape more than just parens

Comment: what do you want to replace?

Comment: @nickzoum I need to replace : "url(../img/content/blocks.svg) no-repeat scroll transparent;" by "none;"

Answer (score 0):

The string to be replaced is a perfect candidate for non-regex based replacement in your case. Unfortunately, JavaScript lacks `replaceAll`, but you may mimic it by combining `split` and `join`:

```
input.split('replace what').join('with what')
```

Demo:

```js
var content = 'some text url(../img/content/blocks.svg) no-repeat scroll transparent; some text url(../img/content/blocks.svg) no-repeat scroll transparent; some text';
var output = content.split('url(../img/content/blocks.svg) no-repeat scroll transparent;').join('none;');
console.log(output);
```